# Choosing Best Nonlinear Model

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction, regularization, fitting

I have some data and I want to fit it to a nonlinear model. With a linear model there is a way to select a model using forward or backward selection. What is a similar method for a nonlinear model in situations where prediction of the model on unseen data is of highest priority?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  This is essentially asking for us to recite the entirety of all literature on model selection.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question but...

Yes, forward and backward selection (FS, BS) are not specific to linear models. FS and BS can be applied to any modeling schema where you have more than 1 input feature to estimate a relationship from. I tend to prefer BS, because I'm not usually limited in computing time/power.

The caret package has done [a lot of this work](https://topepo.github.io/caret/recursive-feature-elimination.html#backwards-selection) for you. It supports BS (implemented as Recursive Feature Elimination) for linear models, tree and forest models, naive Bayes, and other models you could train via caret.

Comment: This is all true, but BS is not a good method.

Comment: Matthew - why? It really depends on the context. If you're driving strictly for model accuracy, for example, it seems like a reasonable tool to have in the toolbox.

Comment: It's just generally very outclassed by ridge, lasso, glmenet etc.  I generally avoid methods that make binary decisions, they are very high variance and there are always better options.

Comment: I haven't found that to be generally true, but we might be working in different contexts. If you count tree based models in the category of "binary decision methods", then I'd disagree. We see tree-based models winning many competitions via xgboost.

Comment: Right, but not individual trees!  You dull the effect of the binary decisions by boosting with a really small learning rate.  So the high variance of the binary decision *is* harmful, and you generally need ways to dull its impact, backwards selection doesn't offer such an option.

Comment: Gotcha. As usual, the answer is "it depends". I'm fond of using backwards selection as a one of my feature importance tools, not necessarily for direct modeling.